# Generic constraints in C#, T is the same TSomethingElse, right?

Tags: c#, generics

I often see:

```
public interface IFoo<TWidget> where TWidget : ISomethingElse { }
```

In this case, TWidget is the same as using the generic T, correct? I'm finding this surprisingly hard to google or find in the specs. I'm 99% sure that T + any other characters is the same as saying just T, but wanted to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the [generic type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) can by any valid identifier name.

In most documentation you would indeed find `T` where you put `TWidget`.

From MSDN:

> Do name generic type parameters with descriptive names, unless a single letter name is completely self explanatory and a descriptive name would not add value.

Comment: Ah the fact it is a generic is determined by where it is, not by the naming convention. This seems all very obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 1):

In this case TWidget is generic, but not because it is T+something. Although it is recommended to name it T+something, it can be anything you want, as long as it syntactically correct type identifier name.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, it's perfectly legal to put any identifier where you usually see `T`.

You'll often see more descriptive names when there are constraints put on the generic type, usually indicating what the constraint might be. It's also helpful to have a longer identifier when you have multiple generic type parameters, so you can easily remember which one is which.

Answer (score 0):

The Type parameter can be names anything but the standard way of doing it is to use T and then go through the alphabet as more generic types are required.

So you might have `public interface IFoo<T, U> where T : ISomethingElse { }`

But you could just as easily use `public interface IFoo<Banana, Spiggot>`. It really doesn't matter